Code coverage dropped after upgrading to storybook 8
I have a web components library written in lit and I was using storybook 7. Now I'm trying to upgrade to storybook 8. Everything is alright besides the code coverage. I'm using interactions test for my project. The tests  are running just fine, but the code coverage dropped. When I check my test coverage reports I see that the only files included are helper files, like enums, but the components files are missing from the report. Before the upgrade around 2.3k lines were evaluated for coverage, but now there are only 300 lines evaluated for coverage. This happens because the components files are not included in the coverage.
Storybook main.cjs file:
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../stories/*.mdx',
    '../stories/update-guide/*.mdx',
    '../stories/theming.stories.ts',
    '../src/**/*.@(mdx|stories.ts)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-coverage',
      options: {
        istanbul: {
          include: ['src/**/*.ts'],
          exclude: [
            'src/tree-view/events/**.ts',
            'src/tree-view/helpers/**.ts',
            'src/common/mixins/**.ts',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    'storybook-addon-pseudo-states',
    '@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm',
    '@storybook/addon-webpack5-compiler-babel',
  ],
  staticDirs: ['../stories/assets', '../themes'],
  features: {
    interactionsDebugger: true,
  },
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/web-components-webpack5',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {},
};


.nycrc.json file:
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}


Storybook packages and versions:
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2276M  CPU @ 2.80GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 21.7.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 10.5.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD <----- active
  Browsers:
    Edge: Chromium (123.0.2420.97)
  npmPackages:
    @storybook/addon-a11y: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-actions: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-coverage: ^1.0.3 => 1.0.3
    @storybook/addon-essentials: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-interactions: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-links: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-mdx-gfm: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/addon-webpack5-compiler-babel: ^3.0.3 => 3.0.3
    @storybook/blocks: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/manager-api: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/test: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/test-runner: ^0.18.1 => 0.18.1
    @storybook/types: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/web-components: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    @storybook/web-components-webpack5: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    eslint-plugin-storybook: 0.8.0 => 0.8.0
    storybook: ^8.1.1 => 8.1.1
    storybook-addon-pseudo-states: ^3.1.1 => 3.1.1

I tried downgrading @storybook/test-runner and @storybook/addon-coverage to previous versions where the coverage worked, but there was no difference. I also tried looking at storybook 8 changelog but I couldn't find anything useful there.
